# Find a Linear transformation $ T:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Find a Linear transformation $ T:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 $ with

(a) Range($T$) =span{(1,1,1)}

(b) Range($T$) =span{(1,2,3),(1,3,2)}

I have done like that. Since Range($T$) =span{(1,1,1)} let us take $T(1,0,0)=(1,1,1)$ and $T(0,1,0)=(0,0,0)$,$\ $  $T(0,0,1)=(0,0,0)$.   And then we can find the transformation. But this transformation is not unique.

Am I right?

Comment: No, it's not unique.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: For example, you could also take $T(1,0,0)=T(0,1,0)=T(0,0,1)=(1,1,1)$ so it is not unique.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got the right idea. Here's an alternate perspective.

Recall that an $n\times m$ matrix $A$ defines a linear map $T:\Bbb R^m\to\Bbb R^n$ by $T(x)=Ax$. In this situation, the column-space of $A$ is equal to the range of $T$
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{Col}{Col}
\DeclareMathOperator{Range}{Range}
\Col(A)=\Range(T)
$$
Since $\Col(A)$ is the span of the columns of $A$ we see that every $3\times 3$ matrix whose columns are scalar multiples of $\langle 1,1,1\rangle$ give an example for (a). Of course, it follows that a linear map with this property is not unique.

Can you construct a matrix that gives an example for (b)?